# Contain contents of fixed aspect box in tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a **fixed aspect ratio** area in my layout using  Tailwind 3. It is defined like so...

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-rows-1">
    <div class="text-xl text-gray-700 lg:text-lg [&>p]:py-5 [&>p]:pl-5">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid place-items-center">
        <div class="aspect-9/16 w-full bg-blue-300 lg:min-h-full lg:w-auto">
            <div>
                wevs
                wevs
                wevs
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this, which is what I want, the bottom parallel with however long the text on the left happens to be. If I add more text on the left the fixed aspect area on the right scales to the height of the content on the left.

[image]

So I want that fixed aspect ratio area to contain its contents without changing size but when I put some extra content into it the whole container grows. Admittedly it grows in the fixed aspect ratio I have set so that is nice, but I'd rather it didn't grow at all!

[image]

Here is a link to a full example on Tailwind Play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/oNjWgFb2AW

With a wide screen (1440px) if you keep adding "wevs" you will see the effect.

I've tried a bunch of way to fix the width and also tried playing with limiting the height fidgeting with the grid values but I'm not having any luck. Everything I've tried seem to either break the aspect ratio part, or the container still scales up with the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `max-h-0` and it works

```
...
<div class="max-h-0 aspect-9/16 w-full bg-blue-300 lg:min-h-full lg:w-auto">
...
```

here is with the example of your playcode 
 https://play.tailwindcss.com/32quTcDj51?size=1440x803

Comment: Thank you Konstantin, that's a great help! While I don't want to look a gift horse in the mouth do you know why that works? It seems a little counterintuitive to me but I'm sure there's just a gap in my understanding around this.

Comment: @RogerHeathcote I had a similar problem a couple of years ago, and I was looking for a solution for a long time. Unfortunately, I don't remember why it works that way. Perhaps when setting the minimum height, css sets other priorities